# How do I set the Priority on client side of MSMQ message sent to a WF Service activated via MQ

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

I have a WCF activated WorkFlow Service (XAMLX) setup (hosted using WorkflowServiceHost).

This WCF WebService has a 'NetMsMqBinding' binding and a net.msmq based endpoint which is used by clients to schedule operations.

On the client side, I've used Visual Studio to generate the proxy stub to communicate to this WCF service. Everything is working fine and I can see the messages appearing in my (journaled) MQ on the server and WCF picking up messages from the queue to activate the configured workflow based on the message.

**I need to control the priority of the messages being sent to MQ so that certain WCF clients can get prioritized processing of their workflows.**

It seems NetMsMqBinding doesn't really support MQ message prioritization. Is this correct? If so, how can I achieve/simulate this? Can I use MQ Triggers to change priority of messages based on some flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my solution, in case someone needs to figure this out

`NetMSMQBinding` does not support setting message priority from the client side so I was using the wrong binding. The more powerful `MsMqIntegrationBinding` is the right way to go.

Client side:
From the client side, one needs to simply create a `System.Messaging.Message` object, set the priority and drop it in the `MessageQueue.MessageQueue` object which points to the destination MQ.

Server side:
The `WorkflowService` hosting WCF project needs the following endpointBinding in the web.config:

---

`<endpoint  address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\MyWebService/MyProcessingService.xamlx"
          binding="msmqIntegrationBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="MyMsMqIntegrationBinding"
          contract="IMyProcessingService"
          name="MqIntegrationBindingEndPoint"
           />`

(the address is assuming MQ service is local to the WCF hosted)

`<bindings>
      <!--We use msmqIntegrationBinding instead of netMsmqBinding since we want to control priority of MQ messages being dropped in the queue 
      and that is not supported in netMsmq
      -->
      <msmqIntegrationBinding>
        <binding name="MyMsMqIntegrationBinding" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </msmqIntegrationBinding>`

---

The way to receive the MsmqMessage from the MQ and process it is by dropping a "Receive" activity in the XAMLX and choosing `Message` as the Content definition MessageType as `System.ServiceModel.MsmqIntegrationMessage<YourTypeGoesHere>` Now you'll have access to this `MsmqMessage<yourType>` from your `ActivityContext` where you can retrieve the value sent in the message.

This is a very useful and powerful way to build a scalable, throttled with priority control MQ+WCF+WF based web service

Comment: No such thing as **System.ServiceModel.MsmqIntegrationMessage**. Did you mean **System.ServiceModel.MsmqIntegration.MsmqMessage<T>**?

Answer (score 1):

Are these transactional messages? If so, you cannot change the priority at all.

Messages are immutable so you can't change the priority of a non-transactional message that has already been sent.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: these aren't transactional messages. I'd like to set the priority of the message ideally from the client side before the message is sent to the receiving queue.

Comment: You can ONLY set the priority of the message in the code of the sending application. Unfortunately I'm not a WCF user so not sure where that would be set.

Comment: yea, that's where I'd like to set it too but netMsmqBinding transparently converts a WCF Soap message to a MSMQ message and vice versa and doesn't give me a call back to control the message properties. Also, I am looking at the legacy MSMQIntegrationBinding but using that is not quite supported in the new Workflow Services paradigm AFAIK